# python3.8 devel package for amazon linux

Tags: docker, python-3.8, amazon-linux-2

I'm building a docker image based on amazonlinux:2.0.20210126.0, my software needs to compile and requires Python.h and other dev resources. I'm installing python3.8 like this in my docker file:

```
RUN amazon-linux-extras enable python3.8
RUN yum install -y python3.8
```

but can't find any devel packages for python3.8 on amazonlinux repos. Tried looking for python3.8-devel or libpython3.8-dev without any success.

Anyone had a similar experience with amazonlinux?

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to get it out of Amazon Extras anymore.  It's available via yum for Amazon Linux2.

Try

```
yum install -y python38 python38-devel
```

Comment: errors: no package python38 or python38-devel abailable